# Zoom shortcut: Replicate "Ctrl + Mouse-Scroll" with keyboard only

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

I can zoom in and out using following shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `mouse scroll`. It works to zoom in **both web browser and text editors**.

**➥ How to emulate the same behaviour, using keyboard keys only?**
(E.g., using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>)

---

I have tried to go to the keyboard shortcut menu and made following changes in section "*Universal Access*":

- Increase/Decrease text size : works well… yet in text editors only (not in web browers);
- Zoom in/out: has no effect whatsoever.